# When to use %d and %f in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, double

I'm new to C programming, but decent in Java, my question is when do we use %d and %f? In what situation? For example, based on the code block given below, if I was asked to take (int)a*(float)y, do I take it as a %d or as a %f?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    float y= 1.5;
    printf("%d \n", a*y);  //do I take this?
    printf("%f", a*y);    //do I take this?
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

745417384
3.000000

Comment: int*float produces a float, so obviously you must use %f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `printf`, `%d` expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`, where `%f` expects it to have type `float` or `double`.

The result of an arithmetic expression involving and `int` and a  `float` will be `float`, so you will need to use `%f` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

> **‘%d’, ‘%i’**: Print an integer as a signed decimal number. See Integer Conversions, for details. ‘%d’ and ‘%i’ are synonymous for output, but are different when used with scanf for input (see Table of Input Conversions).
>
> **‘%f’**: Print a floating-point number in normal (fixed-point) notation. See Floating-Point Conversions, for details.

source: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Table-of-Output-Conversions.html#Table-of-Output-Conversions

Other conversions are possible too

Answer (score 1):

In this case you must use %f, otherwise you will get a strange answer as you saw in your code

Comment: @phuclv: If you are going to be correcting people, you should be clear about the technicalities. There is no rule in the C standard that says a program **must** use `%f` or **must not** use `%d` for a `float` argument. Rather, all the standard says is that it, the standard, does not define the behavior if `%d` is used with a `float`. A reason this distinction is important is that the C standard is deliberately designed to permit and even invite extensions. It often does not forbid programs from doing things but leaves things open for implementations to extend the C language.